# CURL 404 (Yahoo)

Tags: php

I was testing an script that comprove if the domain its working or not and I tested 50 sites (that should work) but just one site (Yahoo) returned "Died" (Not Working) and it returns 404, I'm not sure if the problem is from my code or from the website, I think the problem is the "Redirection" but I don't know what to do.

**How can I follow it?**

```
$host   = "www.yahoo.com";
    $ip     = gethostbyname($host);
    $domain = $ip;
    //Starting process to check the domain
    $check  = curl_init($domain);
    curl_setopt($check, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($check, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($check, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data     = curl_exec($check);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($check, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($check);
    if ($httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode <= 350) {
        $data_array[$key]['status'] = "Alive";
    } else {
        $data_array[$key]['status'] = "Died";
    }
}
```

Comment: try to spoof the user agent and test it out

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Try to add `curl_setopt($check, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` to follow redirect

Comment: @Justinas it didn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the URL like $host   = "www.yahoo.com/"; and added curl_setopt($check, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); it is work for me now.